# Include multiple similar XSLT files without conflict or overriding templates

Tags: xml, xslt, include

I'm trying to devise a way to store data in XSLT files, yet also process them using XSLT to produce an XML file at the end.  These are my two source XSLT files, and the result I am after:

**File 1:**

```
<fruit>
    <xsl:variable name="amount">10</xsl:variable>
    <type>apple</type>
    <quantity><xsl:value-of select="$amount"/></quantity>
    <remaining><xsl:value-of select="$amount / 2"/></remaining>
</fruit>
```

**File 2:**

```
<fruit>
    <xsl:variable name="amount">20</xsl:variable>
    <type>banana</type>
    <quantity><xsl:value-of select="$amount"/></quantity>
    <remaining><xsl:value-of select="$amount / 2"/></remaining>
</fruit>
```

**Output:**

```
Fruit: apple 5/10
Fruit: banana 10/20
```

I have no problem writing the XSLT code to take a single XML file and produce the output I want, but I am stuck with how to combine the two files together.  If I use `<xsl:include>`, then I need to wrap the files in `<xsl:template>` elements which is fine, but then I will have multiple templates the same so I'll either get an error, or with `<xsl:import>` one will be overridden by the other.

I eventually want to extend this to more than two files without having to alter my XSLT code beyond the include/import lines, so it won't work giving each template a custom name, because I want my global XSLT to be able to apply a transform to all `<fruit>` elements, without having to specify each template name manually.

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

**EDIT:** Evidently my simplified example is too simple again, and the comments seem to ask why I would be doing this.  So, here is the same example with different names, making it a bit more specific instead of a general question.  Instead of `<fruit>` try this.  (I am still designing the XML, so I can't post my "real" code as I haven't designed it yet, since I can't do so until I solve this problem.)

**main.xsl:**

```
...
<xsl:variable name="root">/srv</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="baseport">80</xsl:variable>
...
<!-- I don't know how to make this work, as the two (or more) XSL files
     have the same root element -->
<xsl:include href="one.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="two.xsl"/>
...
```

**one.xsl:**

```
...
<file name="one.dat">
    <path><xsl:value-of select="$root">/data</path>
    <backup-path><xsl:value-of select="$root">/data.bak</backup-path>
    <port><xsl:value-of select="$baseport + 1"/></port>
</file>
...
```

**two.xsl**

```
...
<file name="two.dat">
    <path>/var/log</path>
    <backup-path><xsl:value-of select="$root">/backup/var/log</backup-path>
    <port><xsl:value-of select="$baseport + 2"/></port>
</file>
...
```

This will then produce something like:

```
<content for="one.dat">
    path = /srv/data
    backup-path = /srv/data.bak
    port = 81
</content>
<content for="two.dat">
    path = /var/log
    backup-path = /srv/backup/var/log
    port = 82
</content>
```

The XSLT code that produces the `<content>` structure should be considered as "code" (part of my application) but the XSLT code that contains the `<file>` elements is "data" (supplied by users of my application.)  This is why I want to keep my "code" separate from their "data".

My code will first process one user file (`main.xsl`) by feeding it an empty document, to produce an XML document containing many `<file>` elements,  suitable for further transforming.  I can then feed that XML to my application's XSLT code to produce the desired output.

If all the `<file>` elements are listed in `main.xsl` then it's not a problem, I can just process it down to XML (which will contain multiple `<file>` elements) then use an `<xsl:for-each>` to run through each `<file>`.

The problem comes when the users want to split their code into multiple files, with one `<file>` element in each.  They can't use `<xsl:include>` to combine them back together again, as my example above hopefully shows.

In other words, I can't see how to structure `main.xsl` so that it includes both `one.xsl` and `two.xsl`, while keeping both `<file>` elements intact.  It looks like using named templates is the only way, but this adds an extra level of redundancy I want to avoid.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? Your "XSLT files" contain hard-coded data - why don't you simply make them XML files?

Comment: Gladly - but how do I use variables and XSLT's string and other functions if they are XML files?  I know my example is over-simplified, but there are cases when the hard-coded data should be computed from other hard-coded data (in the same file) to avoid redundancy.  I figured making them XSLT rather than just XML was the way to achieve this.

Comment: How is amount variable determined? Is it dependent on fruit type or is it defined by you? This can conceivably be scaled as one XSLT. Please post sample of original XML to illustrate.

Comment: "*there are cases when the hard-coded data should be computed from other hard-coded data (in the same file) to avoid redundancy.*" I am afraid that's too vague. In general, I would say put all your data in the XML file/s and all your logic in a **single** XSLT.

Comment: I have updated my question to be clearer, I hope.  I can't put all the logic in a single XSLT because one XSLT belongs to my application and the other XSLT is data supplied by users of the application.  The `amount` variable is unimportant, the point is that there must be the ability to use variables within the user data, and switching from XML to XSLT is the only way I can see to do this (I am aware that using XML entities is also possible but they lack the full processing power of XSLT, which is why I am hoping to use XSLT for the user data.)

Comment: "*there must be the ability to use variables within the user data*" Well, could you not use XML elements for this, for example: `<backup-path><placeholder key="root">/data.bak</backup-path>`. Then you'll just need one template matching `placeholder` to output the value corresponding to the key (presumably you'll have a dictionary somewhere).

Comment: The problem is I want to allow calculations to be done, like setting the `baseport` variable to `80` and then using `baseport+1` somewhere.  If I stick to XML elements then I'm going to have to re-implement lots of XSL functionality as XML elements, which seems a bit of a waste of effort when I can just use XSLT and all this is available already.